# How to assign two SELECT queries results to single array variable($row)?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

There are two queries with same fields names but different tables. I want fetch both select query's results in same array variable $result. I tried few things but nothing working for me. May b my bad day.

two table, need to be fetch in same variable $result.

```
$sql1="SELECT city,phone,name from table1 where  city='NY'";
$result = $conn->query($sql1);  

$sql2="SELECT city,phone,name from table2 where city='NY'";
$result = $conn->query($sql2);
```

I don't want $result lost $sql1 data after assigning same variable ($result) to second query. Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use UNION and along with that table record identifier to identify table records differently.

```
$sql1   = "(SELECT city,phone,name, 't1' ttype from table1 where city='NY')  
UNION (SELECT city,phone,name,'t2' ttype from table2 where city='NY')";
$result = $conn->query($sql1);
```

> **Note:** MySQL uses the DISTINCT clause as default when executing UNION queries if nothing is specified.

If you want duplicate records too, then use `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql1="SELECT city,phone,name from table1 where  city='NY'
UNION
SELECT city,phone,name from table2 where city='NY'";
 $result = $conn->query($sql1);
```